# warning "an elemental intrinsic function here be of type integer or character"

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, fortran95, fortran2003

I had a line in my code

```
real(8)::pi=4*atan(1D0)
```

I compiled it with `ifort /stand:03` and it warns me

> fortran-learning.f90(3): warning #6009: Fortran 2003 specifies that an
>   elemental  intrinsic function here be of type integer or character and
>   each argument must be an initialization expr of type integer or
>   character.   [ATAN]
>
> ```
>         real(8)::pi=4*atan(1D0)
> ----------------------^
> ```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiler bug has been fixed in recent versions. See [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/506419?language=en) for details.

In Fortran 95, the initialization expressions (constant expressions) were a lot stricter than they are now. The expression you use was not officially supported - hence the warning. 
When this restriction was lifted in Fortran 2003, Intel didn't fix the warning right away - see the linked article. 
Just in case you want to track this, the Intel Issue ID is DPD200253798.

By the way, it is just a warning. You can easily disable it with

```
-diag-disable 6009
```

or on Windows:

```
/Qdiag-disable:6009
```

Comment: real(8)::pi=4*atan(1D0);print*,pi;end
Still reproduces with /stand:f03 on 16.0.2.180. Are you using a beta?

Answer (score 1):

That is a restriction of f95, not f03. Thus a bug in ifort.